# How to show different messages for each element in an array?

Tags: java

I am supposed to have different classes for each product in a store, and if a costumer chooses laptop then it will show the laptop available. How do you create an array of 5 laptops and show the different laptops for each of them? 
This is my tester

```
if (choice == "Laptop"){

    Laptop[] lap = new Laptop[5];

    for (int i = 0; i < lap.length; i++) {
        lap[i] = new Laptop();
    }
    lap[1].msg();
```

Sample output:

```
What do you want to buy?  Laptop

We have 5 different types of laptops:
1.  Manufacturer: HP, Price: $400, Hard drive: 100GB, RAM: 6 GB
2.  Manufacturer: HP, Price: $800, Hard drive: 200GB, RAM: 8 GB
3.  Manufacturer: Dell, Price: $300, Hard drive: 80GB, RAM: 6 GB
4.  Manufacturer: Dell, Price: $680, Hard drive: 150GB, RAM: 8 GB
5.  Manufacturer: Toshiba, Price: $350, Hard drive: 60GB, RAM: 4 GB
```

Comment: `new Laptop()` is always going to create the same thing (unless you use statics, but... don't). You need to parameterise the constructor i.e. `new Laptop(Manufacturer.HP, 400, 100, 6)`. See [Providing Constructors for Your Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html). You won't be able to create these in a loop

Comment: @Makoto While the string comparison **is** incorrect, that's not what he's asking.

Comment: `if (choice == "Laptop")` should be `if (choice.equals("Laptop"))` see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Comment: Show us the code for the `Laptop` class.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are creating a new `Laptop` on each pass of your loop, you're getting identical objects each time. Unless you set the fields in your `Laptop` class, you won't see different data between them.

Instead, your `Laptop` class needs to have it's fields set, either in the constructor (when creating each `Laptop`), or via setters.

Here's a quick and simple demo application you can try out and see it in action:

```
class LaptopDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // First, create some sample laptops and add them to an Array
        Laptop[] laptops = new Laptop[5];

        // You need to create a new laptop and set it's field values
        laptops[0] = new Laptop("HP", 400.00, 100, 6);
        laptops[1] = new Laptop("HP", 800.00, 80, 8);
        laptops[2] = new Laptop("Dell", 300.00, 150, 6);
        laptops[3] = new Laptop("Dell", 680.00, 100, 8);
        laptops[4] = new Laptop("Toshiba", 350.00, 60, 4);

        // Now you can loop through the array and print the details
        for (int i = 0; i < laptops.length; i++) {

            // Build the String to be printed
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append("Manufacturer: ").append(laptops[i].getManufacturer()).append(", ")
                    .append("Price: $").append(laptops[i].getPrice()).append(", ")
                    .append("Hard Drive: ").append(laptops[i].getHdCapacity()).append("GB, ")
                    .append("RAM: ").append(laptops[i].getRamCapacity()).append("GB");

            System.out.println(sb.toString());
        }
    }
}

class Laptop {

    private final String manufacturer;
    private final double price;
    private final int hdCapacity;
    private final int ramCapacity;

    public Laptop(String manufacturer, double price, int hdCapacity, int ramCapacity) {
        this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
        this.price = price;
        this.hdCapacity = hdCapacity;
        this.ramCapacity = ramCapacity;
    }

    public String getManufacturer() {
        return manufacturer;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public int getHdCapacity() {
        return hdCapacity;
    }

    public int getRamCapacity() {
        return ramCapacity;
    }
}
```

> **Results:**

```
Manufacturer: HP, Price: $400.0, Hard Drive: 100GB, RAM: 6GB
Manufacturer: HP, Price: $800.0, Hard Drive: 80GB, RAM: 8GB
Manufacturer: Dell, Price: $300.0, Hard Drive: 150GB, RAM: 6GB
Manufacturer: Dell, Price: $680.0, Hard Drive: 100GB, RAM: 8GB
Manufacturer: Toshiba, Price: $350.0, Hard Drive: 60GB, RAM: 4GB
```